# Can connect locally but not remotely

Tags: php, mongodb, connection, database-connection

I am facing an issue in connecting my php client to my mongodb server.

Basically, I installed MongoDB on my server (hosted in the US), I can connect to it locally when I am connected to it via ssh.

But I can't connect to this server on remote from my php client, here is the error that I get :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017: Connection refused' in /var/www/pages/news.php:9 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/pages/news.php(9): MongoClient->__construct('mongodb://xxx.xxx...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/pages/news.php on line 9

I am using this in order to create a connection from my php client :

```
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
```

My remote server is Ubuntu 12.04 and I already added the INPUT and OUTPUT rules in iptables to allow traffic for the port 27017.

I don't really know where the issue comes from ? (I did not add any authentication credentials to my mongodb instance, its a new one for testing purposes).

If anyone had the same issue and found a solution, it could be helpful, thank you !

Comment: If the connection is still showing refused, I'd still try a basic telnet command from your local to that IP on that port to see if it is available to you. Then you'll know if it is connectivity

Comment: I just tried with telnet, I get a connection refused as well :/

Comment: Sounds like your remote server isn't accepting traffic in on that port. You'll have to confirm you can get outbound connectivity before you can access. You are able to ssh to it so you know that port is open at least

Comment: Thanks Ricky, I can see that the port 22 for ssh is in /etc/services, shall I add the same for mongod : 27017 ?

Comment: I would try following something like this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/

Comment: Ok I found, it was because my mongod instance was bind to the local interface, I'll post my answer tomorrow morning, thanks a lot Ricky !

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, found the issue :

I typed this command in order to display the listening services and their corresponding ports:

```
netstat -anltp | grep "LISTEN"
```

I saw that SSH was listening with the IP : 0.0.0.0
But mongod was listening on the local interface 127.0.0.1

I just had to update the mongodb configuration file here :

/etc/mongodb.conf and set the parameter "bind_ip" to : 0.0.0.0
and uncommented the "port" field to use the default one : 27017.

As a result, now I can connect from my client to my mongod instance on my server.
Hope this helps !